# A doubt regarding the definition of the derivative in Rudin

Tags: real-analysis

On pg. 212 of "Principles of Mathematical Analysis" by Walter Rudin, it says the following:

> $$f(x+h)-f(x)=f'(x)h+r(h)\tag 8$$
>   Note that (8) expresses $f(x+h)-f(x)$ as the sum of the *linear function* that takes $h$ to $f'(x)h$, plus a small remainder.

What is the *linear function* being talked about? And what does "*takes $h$ to $f'(x)h$*" mean? If $f'(x)$ the linear function under consideration? Even then, how does it take $h$ to anything?

Comment: He is talking about the map, defined in $\mathbb R$ by $h\mapsto hf'(x)$.

Comment: @GitGud- Shouldn't he say "sum of _mapping_ of linear function...", rather than "sum of linear function"?

Comment: I think his wording is fine. I don't really understand your suggestion. "Sum of mapping of linear function" makes no sense to me.

Answer (score 1):

When we says a *linear function* that takes $h$ to $f'(x)h$ he means the linear function
$$
L_{f}(h) = h f'(x)
$$
One reason why he may point this out is so that one notices how the derivative, in some sense, is a linear approximation of $f$ at the point $x$.

I see a bunch of other similar (and great) answers have been posted so I'll explain this a bit more in depth.

One way to define the derivative of some $f : \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^m$ at some point $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$ is by defining $M_x = f'(x) \in M_{m \times n}(\mathbb{R})$ to be the matrix satisfying
$$
\lvert f(x + h) - f(x) - M_x h \rvert = o(\lvert h \rvert)
$$
which, if you're unfamiliar with the little $o$ notation is equivalent to saying
$$
\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{\lvert f(x + h) - f(x) - M_x h \rvert}{\lvert h \rvert} = 0
$$
This reveals that the derivative is the linear operator $y \mapsto M_x y$ that best approximates the function at the point $x$.

Of course in one dimension we have $f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ and can consider the matrix $M_x \in M_{1\times1}(\mathbb{R})$ to simply be a real number thus we have
$$
f(x + h) - f(x) - M_x h = o(h) \implies f(x + h) - f(x) = M_x h + o(h)
$$
so that you can see what I'm talking about lines up with what Rudin is talking about.

Answer (score 1):

Fix a point $x$ at which $f$ is differentiable. We have a linear function $L_x : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ given by $L_x(h) = f'(x)h$. Note, as $x$ is fixed, $f'(x)$ is just a constant.

You can think of the domain of $L_x$ as the $x$-axis, but shifted so that the origin is at $x$, and the codomain of $L_x$ as the $y$-axis, but shifted so that the origin is at $f(x)$. The graph of $L_x$ (in these shifted coordinates) is precisely the tangent line to the graph of $f$ at $x$.

Comment: Shouldn't he say "sum of _mapping_ of linear function...", rather than "sum of linear function"?

Comment: I don't think so. I don't even know what you mean by your suggested phrase.

Comment: I meant "sum of image of linear function...", as $f'(x)h$ is the _image_ of the linear mapping that maps $h\to f'(x)h$. But I see how $f'(x)h$ may be a linear function if $h$ is seen as a variable.

Comment: I think it's fine. If $a(h) = b(h) + c(h)$, I would say that $a$ is the sum of the two functions $b$ and $c$.

Answer (score 1):

The sentence

> Note that (8) expresses $f(x+h)-f(x)$ as the sum of the *linear
>   function* that takes $h$ to $f'(x)h$, plus a small remainder.

means that the equation expresses the value $f(x+h)-f(x)$ as the sum of two factors: the linear function $L: h\mapsto f'(x)\cdot h$ and the small remainder function $r$. Their sum, $L(h) + r(h),$ equals $f(x+h)-f(x)$ for every $h$.

Comment: Shouldn't he say "sum of _mapping_ of linear function...", rather than "sum of linear function"?

Comment: @freebird No, it is the sum of two functions, the function $h\mapsto f'(x)\cdot h$ and the function $h\mapsto r(h)$.